# How Do I Mock ResteTemplate exchange without service

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mockito, springmockito

I have a static class which will go to another project get info for what I need when my application starts, since this project has multi sub projects, and other projects need these info for process, so I have to make it static and since I only want one instance exist cross projects, I made the constructor private so when other projects need this info list they only can use this class.getinstance().getList() to get all info, this will force other project using same info list cross sub projects. I did think about to give it a try with put this class in web service project, then everything can be done with Autowired, but the problem is in other sub project, they could not accept Autowired cross projects, so it made the info list I gathered only can be access within web service project, this class located in the utility project, so in my web service project, I have a service to initialize this class and this class should only be initialized once so I give it a private constructor with a get instance method, so web service class will call a configuration method in this class to initialize it and also run a web service call with restTemplate to gather info I need, so this class does not have a service class above it, now I would like to test this class, I made a mockito test with springRunner for it, but it seems not hitting my mocking data.

I have tried several solutions I found with google and seems they all slightly different than my situation, they @InjectMocksof service class and mock the RestTemplat, but my situation it does not need a service class and due to its private constructor I could not inject it either.

Here is my class located in the Utilities project.

```
public class InfoBook
{
//private constructor and config method to set username password and endpoint etc
protected Info LoadInfo()
  {

    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setBasicAuth(username, password);
    final HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

    ResponseEntity<List<InfoResource>> response = null;
    try
    {
      response = restTemplate.exchange(wsEndPoint,
          HttpMethod.GET, request, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<InfoResource>>()
          {
          });
    }
    catch (final RestClientException e)
    {
      //Catch Exception if anything happened during make the rest request, such as connection refused etc.

    }

    Info info = null;
    if (response != null)
    {
      final List<InfoResource> informationList = response.getBody();
      info = InformationMapper.INSTANCE.inforResourceToInfo(informationList.get(0));
    }

    return info ;
  }
}
```

Here is test I made:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class InfoBookTest
{
  @Mock
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Before
  public void setUp()
  {
InfoBook.configInstance("username", "password", "http://localhost:8080");
     List<InfoResource> informationList = new ArrayList<>();
     InfoResource infoResource = new InfoResource();
     // Set content
     informationList.add(infoResource);

     ResponseEntity<List<InfoResource>> response = new ResponseEntity<>(informationList, HttpStatus.OK);

     Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(ArgumentMatchers.any(URI.class),
        ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class), ArgumentMatchers.<HttpEntity<String>> any(),
        ArgumentMatchers.<Class<List<InfoResource>>> any())).thenReturn(response);
  }

  @Test
  public void testloadInfo()
  {
    final Info info=
        InfoBook.getInstance().loadInfo();
    Assert.assertEquals(1000, info.getInfoId());
  }
}
```

now if I ran this test, it trying make a web service call to localhost:8080, and of course it gets an connection refused error. it doesnt seems hit my Mockito when and thenResturn.
Could anybody tells me how could I mock this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your class has a final field of RestTemplate that it initializes with a new, and real `RestTemplate`. Effectively you have no seams for testing so currently it is not possible. You would need to add a field and setter in `InfoBook` that you can call from your test or better yet make InfoBook a service and use a bean and an autowired field. InfoBook can no longer be a singleton, but Spring will only create one anyway so it effectively is one, it just can't have a `static getInstance()`, it will need to be autowired everywhere it is used.

```
@Service
public class InfoBook {
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    //private constructor and config method to set username password and endpoint etc
    protected Info LoadInfo() {

        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setBasicAuth(username, password);
        final HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

        ResponseEntity<List<InfoResource>> response = null;
        try {
            response = restTemplate.exchange(wsEndPoint,
                    HttpMethod.GET, request, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<InfoResource>>() {
                    });
        } catch (final RestClientException e) {
            //Catch Exception if anything happened during make the rest request, such as connection refused etc.

        }

        Info info = null;
        if (response != null) {
            final List<InfoResource> informationList = response.getBody();
            info = InformationMapper.INSTANCE.inforResourceToInfo(informationList.get(0));
        }

        return info;
    }
}
```

You need a configuration class to create the `RestTemplate` bean

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder){
        return restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

Then finally you can just use the Mockito runner for your test and you need to use `@InjectMocks` to create the InfoBook.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class InfoBookTest
{
  @InjectMocks
  private InfoBook infoBook;
  @Mock
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer DCTID, but I need this to be static singleton  because it will also need to be used in other maven sub projects with dependencies include my web service project etc, Im not sure auto wired will be working cross sub projects or not, that is why I wasn't using auto wired at the first place, I could move my restTemplate outside of my method and create a get method for it, so in my test I could get same restTemplate instance, but after that I keep getting uri is not absolute, any idea about this?

Comment: @John usually that means you just have a relative /path and not a full uri like http://localhost:8080/path

Comment: I figured out where is wrong, I put it as an answer for other people who may got same problem, it was a stupid mistake, thank you very much for the help @DCTID

Answer (score 0):

ok, this is very stupid, I thought I better just answer my own question so someone in same or similar situation could get some help, how I solve my problem is I should move restTemplate in InfoBook class outside of the method and give it a get and set method, in my test, I should just set my mock restTemplate then everything will be mocked properly, so instead of I was using real restTemplate, I should use my mocked one, that was why they were different and my mocked data was not returned.

thanks to everyone who helped.